# Bouncing images using the dom

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

I have an idea that I want to implement where various pictures are bouncing around on the screen and the learner has to identify which one is the correct picture.

I did a Google search for [javascript images bouncing](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20images%20bouncing&oq=javascript%20images%20bouncing%20&aqs=chrome..69i57.5380j0j3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and this was the 1st result, which works, but uses Canvas:

```js
var ctx = null;
var x_icon = 0;
var y_icon = 0;
var stepX = 1;
var stepY = 1;
var size_x = 23;
var size_y = 22;
var canvas_size_x = 480;
var canvas_size_y = 320;
var anim_img = null;

function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  anim_img = new Image(size_x, size_y);
  anim_img.onload = function() { setInterval('myAnimation()', 10); }
  anim_img.src = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3352183391/a16302aab7bd8742ad3e39a75454008a_normal.jpeg';
}
function myAnimation() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas_size_x, canvas_size_y);
 if (x_icon < 0 || x_icon > canvas_size_x - size_x) {stepX = -stepX; }
 if (y_icon < 0 || y_icon > canvas_size_y - size_y) {stepY = -stepY; }
  x_icon += stepX;
  y_icon += stepY;
 ctx.drawImage(anim_img, x_icon, y_icon);
}

draw()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320" style="border:solid 1px;"></canvas>
```

I really want to make this a smart phone application, so my thought is to just use the dom and interrogate screen.width and screen.height.

Q: Is there a way to bounce little hyperlink images around a html page without resorting to canvas?

Comment: pretty much exactly what you have. except measure the element size, not the image size, and reference the page size, not the canvas size.

Comment: I'm confused. What does the DOM have to do with anything? Not that it matters because your question is far too broad and will be closed.

Comment: @Rob Why is this too broad? This is a quite clear question and answer.

Comment: "Is there a way" means you want someone to supply you code or other software based on their opinion but will attract other opinions and too much back and forth about how to write the code. There can be no single answer to your question.

Comment: @Rob I don't think this at all creates opinionated questions. There really isn't too many ways to approach this situation, and there really hasn't been any back and forth at all about how to write the code. There may be a few answers: But I doubt that would be a reason for closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use position absolute on the image element, and simply update it's top/left values:

```js
var ctx = null;
var x_icon = 0;
var y_icon = 0;
var stepX = 1;
var stepY = 1;
var size_x = 23;
var size_y = 22;
var anim_img = null;

function draw() {
  anim_img = new Image(size_x, size_y);
  anim_img.onload = function() { setInterval('myAnimation()', 10); }
  anim_img.src = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3352183391/a16302aab7bd8742ad3e39a75454008a_normal.jpeg';
  anim_img.style.position = 'absolute';
  document.body.append(anim_img);
}
function myAnimation() {
  if (x_icon < 0 || x_icon > window.innerHeight - size_x) {stepX = -stepX; }
  if (y_icon < 0 || y_icon > window.innerWidth - size_y) {stepY = -stepY; }
  x_icon += stepX;
  y_icon += stepY;
  anim_img.style.top = x_icon + 'px';
  anim_img.style.left = y_icon + 'px';
}

draw()
```